# Montitor directory for new files

Tags: bash

I have a set of directories, named `00` trough `50`. Each of them contains a logfile.txt, which gets rotated once it hits 10Mb (~each week) to a logfile.old. The old logfile.old will be removed.

I want to make copies of the logfiles, so I would like to make a script that monitors this directories and each time a new logfile.old appears, I want to copy this. I can't change anything in the `00` trough `50` directories or install anything as root.

What's the nicest way to do this under linux (bash)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) provides exactly what you need. Here is the direct [link to the project](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/). You will find plenty of examples by simple google searches.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [rsync](http://inux.die.net/man/1/rsync), run it on a cron job weekly and have it copy the directory to another location